# mongodump dump all but exculde specific collection

Tags: mongodb, dump

I want to dump all my databases and collections except one specific collectioin.
Thought to use --excludeCollection=collection_name but this will dump only one database.
is there any option to do it?

of course i can do this in 2 pahse: dump all except the database containing the collection and then dump this database and exculde the collection. but maybe there's a way to do it in 1 dump?

Comment: no way in mongodump command, but you can create a sh script or any python script by your logic.